# Can I Skip linking assemblies in UWP Project?

Tags: c#, json, uwp, json.net, xamarin.uwp

I use xamarin forms. I have problem with "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject" NullReferenceException crash on Xamarin.UWP only in Release mode (in Debug work, but in Release not). I saw, that I can add System.Core;System.Runtime.Serialization to the Skip linking assemblies to fix it. In Android Project I found this menu, but in UWP project not. What can I do?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue on Xamarin.uwp. 
I searched for a lot of similar problems, most of them are Xamarin.android related issues. Could you provide more code ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks, I already solved the problem)

Comment: Could you please share the solution with me? So that other users who come cross this issue can have a reference.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes, Solution is simple do not use json converter when you use "DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content, new MyJsonConverter());" - it give null reference exeption on UWP in release mode. For right work you should use DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content). And if you want to use converter you can use attribute [JsonConstructor] or JsonConverter(typeof(MyClass))] in MyClass description. It works correctly)

Comment: Could I edit your comment  as answer for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited @Dmitrii Kurylev's comment as the answer. if other users who come cross this issue, please reference following reply.

> Solution is simple do not use json converter when you use the following code .it give null reference exeption on UWP in release mode.

`DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content, new MyJsonConverter());`

> For right work you should use

`DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content)`

> And if you want to use `converter` you can use attribute `[JsonConstructor]` or `JsonConverter(typeof(MyClass))]` in `MyClass` description. It will  work correctly.